# pydantic - Avoid using the stringified attribute name when using model_instance.copy(update={

Tags: python, pydantic

Let's say we have simple Model

```
class Box(BaseModel):
    id: str
    size: str

box = Box(id='1', size='10x10')
```

when i want to create an instance with an updated attribute (e.g. size) I would use:

```
updated_box = box.copy(update={'size':'20x40'})
```

But I want to avoid using the 'size' string. If i ever change my model, for example like this,

```
class Box(BaseModel):
    id: str
    size_x: int
    size_y: int
```

I will not get a type error from the editor, since I'm just using a string and I'll have to find all the places in the code where I used the copy-update mechanism.

Is there any way to do this that i get my type hint errors in this case?